# Calculate heart rate from PPG

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, matlab

I'm working on iOS application for PPG recording and heart rate calculation for my graduation project.

I implemented an algorithm for recording PPG and detecting peaks. Now I need reliable algorithm for calculating number of beats per minute (from 10-15 seconds long PPG). Here is what I have after recording signal and calling PeakFinder method:

[image]

Comment: So... what is your question ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: If you have number of peaks and duration in seconds, shouldn't your BPM just be (num_peaks/sec)*60?

Comment: Yeah, but what's the most accurate way for calculation: using average distance between two peaks, using most frequent distance, using your formula or something else. I'm asking for advices.

Comment: First you are going to have to remove the first and last peaks, then you can do whatever you want.  The most accurate would probably be to get an array of beat durations, remove statistical anomalies and average them.  Then you can get an average beats per second with a standard deviation calculation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 2 methods:

1. Peaks counting: Detect peaks in the data. Calculate distance between 1 adjacent peaks.

`BPM=(Sampling Rate/(peak(i+1)-peak(i)))*60;`

2. Do the FFT transform for a set of data. Then find the peak from 0.5-2.5Hz. Finally multiply that peak's frequency with 60s.

Answer (score 0):

Discard the first and last peaks, since it looks from your graph like the last one isn't really a peak, and something similar could also happen to the first one.

The remaining peaks range from the second peak to the penultimate peak.

Use as your heart rate:

60 * ((number of remaining peaks) - 1) / ((time of penultimate peak) - (time of second peak))

This is essentially how a nurse would do it when counting your pulse - the rate is the number of beats divided by the time.  The result is based on mean distance between peaks, which is probably more valid for this application than a median distance.